# Un-initialized double has value carried over in second call to function (Head First C Example)

Tags: c, linux

So I am teaching myself programming and I was working on the price_drinks.c program from the "Head First C" book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

enum drink { MUDSLIDE, FUZZY_NAVEL, MONKEY_GLAND, ZOMBIE };

double price(enum drink d){
    switch(d) {
    case MUDSLIDE:
    return 6.79;
    case FUZZY_NAVEL:
    return 5.31;
    case MONKEY_GLAND:
    return 4.82;
    case ZOMBIE:
    return 5.89;
    }
    return 0;
}

double total(int args, ...){
    double total;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, args);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < args; i += 1){
        enum drink d = va_arg(ap, enum drink);
        total = total + price(d);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return total;
}

int main(){

    printf("Price is %.2f\n", total(2, MONKEY_GLAND, MUDSLIDE));
    printf("Price is %.2f\n", total(3, MONKEY_GLAND, MUDSLIDE, FUZZY_NAVEL));
    printf("Price is %.2f\n", total(1, ZOMBIE));

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I decided to not initialize the variable total in the function total to 0, this causes a strange error for me, the output from this program is:

```
$ ./a.out 
Price is 11.61
Price is 16.92
Price is 22.81
```

Where the first two outputs appear to be fine, automatically setting total = 0, however the third call of the function appears to carry over the value from the previous call. I was just curious as to why that might be happening?

I understand best practices probably dictates that you always initialize your variables, I was just being lazy and came across this strange bug.

Comment: Your code has *undefined behaviour*. You can't expect it to produce any particular output.

Comment: Thanks, I will make sure to initialize my variables from now on!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting some random values from the stack. It can be anything.

It's not best practices. You must initialize your variables before using them. Or anything can happen.